# MPAndroidChart multidataset barchart. String in x axis?

Tags: android, bar-chart, mpandroidchart

I'm using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). I want to draw a bar chart with some datasets, but in my x axis I have string datatype not float.
For example, this chart with ice cream flavors in X, sales (number) in Y and 2 datasets:

[image: ice cream flavors sales]

[BarDataSet](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/) is a collection of [BarEntry](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/v3.1.0/javadoc/com/github/mikephil/charting/data/BarEntry.html), which is a tuple of x and y float values.

Is it possible to associate strings + numbers in BarEntry?

Answer (score 0):

MpChart only supports float in both X and Y, so you have make the mapping yourself. For example 1.0f means chocolate, 2.0f means vanilla, 3.0f means strawberry, and convert the display format in ValueFormatter like this:

```
object: ValueFormatter() {
override fun getAxisLabel(value: Float, axis: AxisBase): String {
  return getFormattedValue(value)
}

override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float)
  = when(value) {
        1.0f -> "chocolate"; 
        2.0f -> "vanilla"; 
        3.0f -> "strawberry"; 
        else -> ""
   }
```